# adding key/value to all nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion, data-structures

I have an array of objects, which has an array of objects inside (it also has another one inside).

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The question is how to enter a new key value in each one so that it looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    isChecked: false,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isChecked: false,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        isChecked: false,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1,
            isChecked: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I know that iterating can be achieved

```
array.map(object => {
  return {
    ...object,
    isChecked: false
  }
})
```

but is there a better way to do it?
some way that all objects have that key/value without iterating multiple times

Comment: You need a recursive function so you can process the nested arrays.

Comment: It might also be worth thinking about another approach e.g. create a `checked` Map that can be used to identify each of the sub-objects that have been checked, rather than to litter that state within the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it recursively with a one-liner like this:

```js
const array = [{"id":1,"prod":[{"id":1,"op":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]},{"id":2,"op":[{"id":1}]}]},{"id":2,"prod":[{"id":1,"op":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]},{"id":2,"op":[{"id":1}]}]}]

const f = v => v instanceof Object && (
  !Array.isArray(v) && (v.isChecked = false),
  Object.values(v).forEach(f)
)

f(array)
console.log(array)
```

It adds `isChecked = false` only for regular (non-array) objects, and recurses for all items in the object (which will include both object property values and array elements).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively regardless of the number and names of the array properties. The only problem you should insert the `isChecked` after `id` so we should do that explicitly.

Note that we don't use `Object.XXX` methods and spread syntax here, because they are slow.

```js
const addCheck = arr => arr.map(item => {
  const out = {};
  for(const key in item) { 
    const val = item[key];
    out[key] = Array.isArray(val) ? addCheck(val) : val; 
    if(key === 'id') out.isChecked = false;
  }
  return out;
});

console.log(addCheck(array));
```

```html
<script>
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    prod: [
      {
        id: 1,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        op: [
          {
            id: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The next provided generic (in terms of data structure) and recursive implementation exclusively targets array items which [feature an own `id` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

And since key insertion order does not matter, each matching sub-structure's reference gets mutated directly by assigning the `isChecked`  property to it.

It also makes a distinction in between array types and any other object type, since [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) are not fully bullet proof. The former iterates over any enumerable string-keyed property value, thus also iterating over any of an array's non integer properties (yes, a rare case), and the latter *"... [MDN] ...iterates over all enumerable string properties of an object (ignoring properties keyed by symbols), including inherited enumerable properties"*.

```js
function mutateOwnIdEntriesRecursively(data) {
  if (data && typeof data === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {

      data
        .forEach(mutateOwnIdEntriesRecursively);
    } else {
      Object
        .values(data)
        .forEach(mutateOwnIdEntriesRecursively);

      if (data.hasOwnProperty('id')) {

        data.isChecked = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
const sampleData = [{id:1,prod:[{id:1,op:[{id:1},{id:2}]},{id:2,op:[{id:1}]}]},{id:2,prod:[{id:1,op:[{id:1},{id:2}]},{id:2,op:[{id:1}]}]}];

mutateOwnIdEntriesRecursively(sampleData)

console.log({ sampleData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A recent edit brought this older question to the fore, and I have a somewhat different approach.  The accepted answer does something that to me is verboten: it modifies the input.  Here's a version that creates a new object with the key-value included.

```js
const addNestedProp = (name, val) => (o) => 
  Array.isArray (o)
    ? o.map (addNestedProp(name, val))
  : Object(o) === o
    ? Object.fromEntries([
        ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, addNestedProp(name, val)(v)]),
        [name, val], 
      ])
  : o

const array = [{id:  1, prod: [{id: 1, op: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}, {id: 2, op: [{id: 1}]}]}, {id: 2, prod: [{id: 1, op: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}, {id: 2, op: [{id: 1}]}]}]

console.log(addNestedProp('isChecked', false)(array))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This version also makes the key and value to set (`"isChecked"`/`false`) parameters rather than hard-coding them.

The code has three branches:

- for an array, it simply recurs on each element
- for an object, it pulls it apart into key-value entries, recurs on each of those values, adds your targeted key and value into another entry, and puts an object back together out of those.
- for anything else, it returns the original intact.